# Add order # to USPS shipping label

Tags: shipping, usps

We are using the default Magento CE v 1.9.1.0 USPS shipping functionality. We have our api credentials allowed to create a shipping label.

However when we create a USPS shipping label inside the usps.com website their is an option to add a reference # to the shipping label which we use to add the order number onto the label.

However now that we are using Magento to create the shipping labels we do not see the order # on the shipping label that Magento developers and would like to now how to alter the code to send the order # as a ference # to USPS when we have Magento generate the shipping label.

Any suggestions on the file to edit?

Comment: I had a module already that was extending the USPS function to remove the # of days shown next to each USPS shipping method. what I did was add your code to the directories/files I already had setup. However now what is happening is the checkout page seems to break when I go to it on our test site. By break I mean the page loads up to the area where the shipping methods would normally be listed and then the page seems to stop and the remainder of the page does not get loaded. I will post my code below with directories so you can maybe give some suggestions how to fix.

Comment: app/code/local/Exormedia/Usps/etc/config.xml
- http://pastebin.com/iJn59d1x

app/code/local/Exormedia/Usps/Mode/Shipping/Shipment/Request.php
- http://pastebin.com/FQTLwcGq

app/code/local/Exormedia/Usps/Mode/Shipping/Shipping.php -
http://pastebin.com/yg5YU4rc

app/code/local/Exormedia/Usps/Model/Usa/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
- http://pastebin.com/HzDxs751

Comment: app/etc/modules/Exormedia_Usps.xml - http://pastebin.com/8NhbdvJR

Comment: Hey - sorry, I don't get notifications when you comment directly on your question. If you comment on an answer, the user that posted it will get notified. I am out at the moment, but when I am back at the computer I will take a look!

Comment: I ran your code, and there are no issues here. In your Exormedia_Usps_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Usps you are missing a closing } on your if statement on line 7, and on line 413 you have an extra } which you should remove. I ran a few sales with the  $name = preg_replace('/\s+?\d+-day/i', '', $name); outside of an if statement, and had no issues. The preg_replace doesn't do anything, at least not using the rwd theme, but there were no errors. I think your original question is  answered, so if you want to look further at your new issue accept my answer below and submit a new question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add information to the label, you must modify the xml sent to USPS. Magento collects your shipment information, converts it to xml, then sends it to the USPS api, which returns an image file. Magento then takes that image and creates the pdf you get when you click on "Print Shipping Label".

There is a tag in the api called "CustomerRefNo" which seems right for your purposes. In case you want to try something else, the usps reference is [here](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/delivery-confirmation-domestic-shipping-label-api.htm)

In order to accomplish this, I have created a module called Yourcompany_UspsLabel. I will include all of the contents for clarity.

**app/code/local/Yourcompany/UspsLabel/etc/config.xml**

Basically lets Magento know about what you are rewriting.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_UspsLabel>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Yourcompany_UspsLabel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourcompany_uspslabel>
                <class>Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>yourcompany_uspslabel_resource</resourceModel>
            </yourcompany_uspslabel>
            <yourcompany_uspslabel_resource>
                <class>Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Resource</class>
            </yourcompany_uspslabel_resource>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping>Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipping</shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
            <usa>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping_carrier_usps>Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Usps</shipping_carrier_usps>
                </rewrite>
            </usa>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <yourcompany_uspslabel>
                <class>Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Helper</class>
            </yourcompany_uspslabel>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Yourcompany/UspsLabel/Model/Shipping/Shipment/Request.php**

Note the @methods at the end - getOrderId and setOrderId to make these available when this object is passed.

```
/**
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setOrderShipment(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment $orderShipment)
 * @method Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment getOrderShipment()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperContactPersonName(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperContactPersonName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperContactPersonFirstName(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperContactPersonFirstName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperContactPersonLastName(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperContactPersonLastName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperContactCompanyName(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperContactCompanyName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperContactPhoneNumber(int $value)
 * @method int getShipperContactPhoneNumber()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressStreet(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressStreet()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressStreet1(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressStreet1()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressStreet2(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressStreet2()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressCity(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressCity()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressStateOrProvinceCode(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressStateOrProvinceCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressPostalCode(int $value)
 * @method int getShipperAddressPostalCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShipperAddressCountryCode(string $value)
 * @method string getShipperAddressCountryCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientContactPersonName(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientContactPersonName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientContactPersonFirstName(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientContactPersonFirstName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientContactPersonLastName(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientContactPersonLastName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientContactCompanyName(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientContactCompanyName()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientContactPhoneNumber(int $value)
 * @method int getRecipientContactPhoneNumber()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressStreet(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressStreet()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressStreet1(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressStreet1()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressStreet2(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressStreet2()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressCity(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressCity()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressStateOrProvinceCode(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressStateOrProvinceCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressPostalCode(int $value)
 * @method int getRecipientAddressPostalCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setRecipientAddressCountryCode(string $value)
 * @method string getRecipientAddressCountryCode()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setShippingMethod(string $value)
 * @method string getShippingMethod()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setPackageWeight(float $value)
 * @method float getPackageWeight()
 * @method Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request setOrderId(string $value)
 * @method string getOrderId()
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Shipping
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipment_Request extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipment_Request
{
}
```

**app/code/local/Yourcompany/UspsLabel/Model/Shipping/Shipping.php**

The only change here is adding in the order's Increment ID - `$request->setOrderId($order->getIncrementId());`, at the end of the `requestToShipment` function.

```
<?php

class Yourcompany_UspsLabel_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function requestToShipment(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment $orderShipment)
    {
        $admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        $order = $orderShipment->getOrder();
        $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingMethod(true);
        $shipmentStoreId = $orderShipment->getStoreId();
        $shipmentCarrier = $order->getShippingCarrier();
        $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore($shipmentStoreId)->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        if (!$shipmentCarrier) {
            Mage::throwException('Invalid carrier: ' . $shippingMethod->getCarrierCode());
        }
        $shipperRegionCode = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_REGION_ID, $shipmentStoreId);
        if (is_numeric($shipperRegionCode)) {
            $shipperRegionCode = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($shipperRegionCode)->getCode();
        }

        $recipientRegionCode = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($address->getRegionId())->getCode();

        $originStreet1 = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ADDRESS1, $shipmentStoreId);
        $originStreet2 = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ADDRESS2, $shipmentStoreId);
        $storeInfo = new Varien_Object(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information', $shipmentStoreId));

        if (!$admin->getFirstname() || !$admin->getLastname() || !$storeInfo->getName() || !$storeInfo->getPhone()
            || !$originStreet1 || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY, $shipmentStoreId)
            || !$shipperRegionCode || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP, $shipmentStoreId)
            || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID, $shipmentStoreId)
        ) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Insufficient information to create shipping label(s). Please verify your Store Information and Shipping Settings.')
            );
        }

        /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipment_Request */
        $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/shipment_request');
        $request->setOrderShipment($orderShipment);
        $request->setShipperContactPersonName($admin->getName());
        $request->setShipperContactPersonFirstName($admin->getFirstname());
        $request->setShipperContactPersonLastName($admin->getLastname());
        $request->setShipperContactCompanyName($storeInfo->getName());
        $request->setShipperContactPhoneNumber($storeInfo->getPhone());
        $request->setShipperEmail($admin->getEmail());
        $request->setShipperAddressStreet(trim($originStreet1 . ' ' . $originStreet2));
        $request->setShipperAddressStreet1($originStreet1);
        $request->setShipperAddressStreet2($originStreet2);
        $request->setShipperAddressCity(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_CITY, $shipmentStoreId));
        $request->setShipperAddressStateOrProvinceCode($shipperRegionCode);
        $request->setShipperAddressPostalCode(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_ZIP, $shipmentStoreId));
        $request->setShipperAddressCountryCode(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID, $shipmentStoreId));
        $request->setRecipientContactPersonName(trim($address->getFirstname() . ' ' . $address->getLastname()));
        $request->setRecipientContactPersonFirstName($address->getFirstname());
        $request->setRecipientContactPersonLastName($address->getLastname());
        $request->setRecipientContactCompanyName($address->getCompany());
        $request->setRecipientContactPhoneNumber($address->getTelephone());
        $request->setRecipientEmail($address->getEmail());
        $request->setRecipientAddressStreet(trim($address->getStreet1() . ' ' . $address->getStreet2()));
        $request->setRecipientAddressStreet1($address->getStreet1());
        $request->setRecipientAddressStreet2($address->getStreet2());
        $request->setRecipientAddressCity($address->getCity());
        $request->setRecipientAddressStateOrProvinceCode($address->getRegionCode());
        $request->setRecipientAddressRegionCode($recipientRegionCode);
        $request->setRecipientAddressPostalCode($address->getPostcode());
        $request->setRecipientAddressCountryCode($address->getCountryId());
        $request->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod->getMethod());
        $request->setPackageWeight($order->getWeight());
        $request->setPackages($orderShipment->getPackages());
        $request->setBaseCurrencyCode($baseCurrencyCode);
        $request->setStoreId($shipmentStoreId);
        $request->setOrderId($order->getIncrementId());

        return $shipmentCarrier->requestToShipment($request);
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Yourcompany/UspsLabel/Model/Usa/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php**

StackExchange is stopping me from pasting the next bit, as it goes over the character limit. I created a paste [here](http://pastebin.com/RXXrL8Ck). The changes in this file are simple - just add `$xml->addChild('CustomerRefNo', $request->getOrderId());` to each of the xml creation functions - `_formUsExpressShipmentRequest`, `_formUsSignatureConfirmationShipmentRequest`, and `_formIntlShipmentRequest`. This should be added *after* the `$xml->addChild('ImageType', 'PDF');` calls.

**app/etc/modules/Yourcompany_UspsLabel.xml**
Because, well, you will need one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_UspsLabel>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Yourcompany_UspsLabel>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You can see the order number on the label - It's on the right, under weight - Ref:145000008.

[image: label with order number]